# updating a row to implement error trapping

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

Please any ideas on how I can achieve the result shown in the attached picture .For now I have all the rows of the error field initiated with a default value of '0' and update the field based on different conditions but for the result .Its a bit challenging since its based on comparing 2 rows.
**The logic that allows episodes to be condensed into a single continuous care episode is a discharge code of 22 followed by an admission code of 4 on the same day. So if a discharged code of 22 is followed by a different code other than an admission code of 4 for the same day that is an invalid entry.

```sql
                       drop table #source
                     CREATE TABLE #source(patidid varchar(20),epn int,preadmitdate datetime,adminttime varchar(10),
                 admitcode varchar(10),admittype varchar(25),datedischarge datetime,disctime varchar(10),disccode varchar(10),dischargetype varchar(20),errorcode int)
                INSERT INTO #source VALUES
                 (1849,1,'4/23/2020','7:29',1,'First Admission','7/31/2020','9:03',22,'Campus Transfer',0)
                ,(1849,2,'7/31/2020','11:00',4,'Campus Transfer','7/31/2020','12:09',22,'Campus Transfer',0)
                ,(1849,3,'7/31/2020','13:10',2,'Re-Admission',null,null,null,null,0)

select * from #source
```

[image: error_trapping desires output]

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I have interpereted your requirement correctly it appears a simple use of `lag()` might be all you need

```
select epn, preadmitdate, adminttime, admitcode, null admit_value, datedischarge, disctime, disccode, null disc_value, 10 [Error_Number], 'Error message' [Error_Description]
from (
    select *, Lag(disccode,1) over(order by epn) PrevDiscCode
    from #source
)t
where PrevDiscCode=22 and admitcode !=4
```

Comment: Thanks @Stu .Your code was helpful and worked for this 1 record in the test data  but not giving me the desired result for multiple records i.e different patid's  because I stated the error field is initiated a zero and supposed to be updated to the present error code of 10 before its been inserted into the error output table.

Comment: Ok, it probably just needs a `partition` clause over the PatIDs - try that and if no good, post some more real-world representative sample data it's definitely doable.